# Heroku ACM not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, heroku-cli

I have a RoR app hosted in Heroku and I'm trying to set my custom domains. In fact, I want three custom domains: www.myapp.org, www.myapp.eu and www.myapp.es.

I have configured my DNS to point to the DNS targets provided by Heroku. I have the .eu and .es domains registered in www.piensasolutions.com and the .org in cloudns.

The redirection works perfectly fine but I have discovered that ACM is unable to generate certificates for my .es domain. The other 2 work perfectly fine (.org and .eu) but the .es is failing. Even though is configured exactly the same as the .eu one, as they are both registered in the same site.

I have tried to see the status of the certifications using `heroku certs:auto` and it says "Failing" for the "www.myapp.es"

Answer (score 2):

It was a matter of time. Seems like certificating a local domain like .es is slower for the Heroku ACM. After nearly 20h everything is set up. Sorry for the time waste.

Comment: I find the "green tick" a little misleading if it takes another 20 hours to "activate"